# How to get photos to be under 500 pixels

Tags: pixels

How do I set my Nikon 5100 to shoot pictures that come out under 500 pixels? I want to upload pictures to my website.

Comment: Uh...... you do know you can resize images, right?

Comment: That's not very many pixels. It's 22x22 pixels. That's tiny. In any event you can resize it in any image editing program.

Comment: Upload it on 500px! ;)

Comment: This is an image manipulation question as cameras do not support on-the-fly resizing.

Comment: @TFuto Sure they do. Most let you select from a number of resolutions before shooting. And some even let you do it after the fact.

Comment: @MichaelClark: choosing the resolution before shooting is technically not on-the-fly *conversion*, it is *encoding*. Conversion usually involves decoding to a target representation space and then re-encode it.

Comment: @TFuto Choosing the resolution in camera means that the sensor output is read at *full resolution* and then the image is *resized* when it is *converted* to JPEG. So *YES*, it really is on-the-fly conversion.

Comment: @MichaelClark: Thanks for the lecture ;-). But the only conversion that takes place there is the ADC, which is not image manipulation. After that, the saving in RAW or JPEG is properly called encoding, not conversion. From sensor to JPEG, you do a raw data-to-encoded-form *encoding* (it can be resized, contrast-enhanced, whatever - it is part of the encoding pipeline). If you take a "cooked" dataset, a JPEG, you decode it to an immediate representation where resizing and other image manipulation is meaningful and then re-encode it. The encode-decode sequence is called "conversion" colloquially

Comment: @TFuto Okay, let me rephrase my original comment without using the word *conversion* in reply to your comment: "This is an image manipulation question as cameras do not support on-the-fly *resizing*." Sure they do. Most let you select from a number of resolutions before shooting. And some even let you do it after the fact.

Comment: @TFuto Choosing the resolution in camera means that the sensor output is read at *full resolution* and then the image is *resized* when it is *encoded* to JPEG. So YES, it really is on-the-fly *resizing*. Since, as you say, "...it can be resized, contrast-enhanced, whatever - it is part of the encoding pipeline).

Comment: @MichaelClark: they support on-the-fly image *sizing*, not re-sizing. Anyway, I think this has been discussed too much ;-).

Answer (score 7):

You don't. The camera can save files in three resolutions:

- 4,928 x 3,264 [L]
- 3,696 x 2,448 [M]
- 2,464 x 1,632 [S]

After taking a photo, you can use the "Retouch" menu's options to help you, though. The "Resize" option will let you resize an image down to 320 x 216. (Consult page 184 of the [manual](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17325/~/users-manual---d5100) for specific steps.) To be honest, I would not use this feature and would prefer to resize an image after I've got it on my computer and can better work with it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of applications that can resize your image.  In most of those you can set the size of the longest direction (vertical or horizontal) to 500 and have the program calculate the size of the other direction.     One free such program is paint.net (Windows only).

Comment: The normal version of paint now allows this also.

Comment: IrfanView, too. :-)